# How to select a subform record and display in a popup mainform

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

When you select a ID field then the subform record must display in a mainform like when you select the subform record you must be able to edit that specific record in a popup mainform. This is a project and im been struggling it to get it to work

My popup mainform is Inventory Details and primary is ID
My subform name is Customerssubform and foreign key is ID

I was able to open the form but it goes to a new record it must go to a specific record according your selection

My Code

```
Private Sub ID_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

 DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="Inventory Details", OpenArgs:=Me.ID
 Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

  If Len(Me.OpenArgs & "") > 0 Then
  Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone

  With rst
  .FindFirst "ID = " & Me.OpenArgs
  If Not .EOF Then Me.Bookmark = .Bookmark

  End With
  End If
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This section of code:

```
 Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

  If Len(Me.OpenArgs & "") > 0 Then
  Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone

  With rst
  .FindFirst "ID = " & Me.OpenArgs
  If Not .EOF Then Me.Bookmark = .Bookmark

  End With
  End If
```

Should all be in the `Form_Open` event of the `Inventory Details` form. Change that to make it work.

Comment: Thanks Erik i didnt put it on the Form_Open i put the code in the Form_Load event. Thanks so much really appreciate it